# Configure error

Tags: 12.04

```
root@ubuntu:/home/mase/Downloads/soft/netmate-da-1-0-2/netmate# ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
[...]
checking readline/readline.h usability... yes
checking readline/readline.h presence... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking readline/history.h usability... yes
checking readline/history.h presence... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline in -lreadline... no
**configure: error: cannot find libreadline**
```

Comment: What are you trying to install and please paste the complete output?

Comment: type this in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline5`